Enormous variability in time series forecasting model. How would you deal with it?
I am working on a difficult physical time series forecasting model with tensorflow.
The model is a binary classifier with around 100 features, which basically consists of 4 LSTM layers (input + 2 hidden + output), with standard activation/initialization function/strategy and is Adam-optimized with standard parameters also (no LR scheduling).
The loss function is binary crossentropy, and I regularize the model through relatively high dropout and recurrent dropout plus early stopping on the loss. Benefits of L1 and L2 regularizers were refuted in CV hyperparameter tuning, same for normalization strategies such as gradient clipping or layer normalization (although I only tested the last positioned after activation functions).
The model is fine -- on some fits. Fitting the model, with exact same parameters and with tf.set_random_seed (and the analogous numpy parameter) called at the beginning of the code, sometimes I obtain a nice model, and in others a worse than mediocre one.
Performance, as measured by global metrics such as Average Precision Score, on a single fixed test set (early stopping running on a separate, also fixed validation set) vary by as much as 25%.
I have no idea how to deal with this. How to obtain more stability between 'different instances of the same model'? How could I test stuff like feature selection, set benchmarks for more complex architectures or even perform hyperparameter tuning if the results cannot be trusted to be consistent? How to select one specific fit to deploy/perform inference? I suppose ensembles could be a solution, but it sounds messy.
I am a beginner on this sort of stuff and welcome any insight.

Differencing of variables could be an issue due to non-stationary time-series. What is the lookback window for LSTM cells? How do the plots look for actual vs predictions for each model? This post can be a good beginner's guide.

Thank you very much for your help!
Shouldn't, even with collinear variables or such, the setting of the random seeds make the runs reproducible?

Since you are using Adam-Optimizer which is deterministic, with same set of hyperparameters, same seed for data generation and optimizer, same LSTM architecture, the results should be reproducible in theory.  Things that could still affect randomness are environment and OS that you are running in. Please check this.
